# How do I change the default landing page in a Trac wiki?

Tags: trac, bug-tracking

A default Trac installation will display the WikiStart page as its home page. I'd like it to display another page. How do I do that? I was unable to find anything with Google, as any request with "Trac" in it will return links to every opensource project that uses Trac.

Comment: Should be migrated to Serverfault

Comment: For those 1.X users: `trac-admin /path/to/project wiki rename WikiStart WikiDocsStart`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to keep the "Welcome to Trac" page, have you considered simply migrating that content to a new page  and then editing WikiStart?  Trac documentation upgrades leave the WikiStart page unchanged (as documented [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracUpgrade#UpdatetheTracDocumentation)), so you aren't making trouble for yourself in that regard.

Answer (score 5):

Are you wanting to display a different wiki page, or a different kind of page?  I don't know of a config option for the former, but you can use `[trac] default_handler` in your `trac.ini` to make, say, the custom query page be the default page.

**Edit:** Taking a quick glance over the sources, WikiStart is pretty well hard-coded as the start page for the wiki.  So, short of patching Trac, I don't think you can do what you're after.

Comment: A different wiki page. By default, Trac shows the "Welcome to Trac" page. I'd like to keep that page but have another one as the default landing page.

Comment: If you use the default_handler from trac.ini
You could create a simple plugin overloading your WikiModule Class, and then return a different page than WikiStart. But this would involve a little Python hacking.

Answer (score 5):

It seems there's no hope in overriding `/wiki` URL path to render a wiki page other than `WikiStart`. That's hardcoded by design (maybe for a very good reason).

On the other hand you can use configuration options in `[mainnav]` section to override `Wiki` link in main navigation area and make it point at a custom wiki page e.g.

```
[mainnav]
wiki.label = Home
wiki.href = /wiki/HomePage
```

see details in [trac:wiki:TracInterfaceCustomization#CustomNavigationEntries](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization#CustomNavigationEntries)

Comment: Best solution so far!

Answer (score 0):

If your Trac installation is behind Apache, then you can use an Apache configuration directive to redirect or rename the "home page" url.  For example, look at the "Alias" directive.

Comment: Yes I am behind Apache, but is there really no way I can configure Trac itself to show a certain page when requesting /projectname/wiki?

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the same problem was to use the `[[Include]]` macro (http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/IncludeMacro), and have the WikiStart page contain a single include statement.

I wanted a different page name than WikiStart so I could use the page name prefixes to categorize sets of pages, e.g., MyToolNameIntroduction is my start page.

Answer (score 0):

This trac ticket suggests it is not directly possible: http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/9012